# How to use PhantomJS on an application server

Tags: java, maven, phantomjs, vaadin, wildfly

I am using Vaadin for my web application and I build with Maven and deploy the ear application on a Wildfly 8.2 application server.

I want to use the [SVG Generator of Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/charts/java-api/charts-advanced.html#charts.advanced.export.svggenerator) to generate my charts on the server-side.

> The generator uses PhantomJS to render the chart on the server-side.

I have to install somehow or other PhantomJS in order to do that.

Because if I don't I get an error of course:

```
17:18:34,587 SEVERE [com.vaadin.server.DefaultErrorHandler] (default task-113) : java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "phantomjs": CreateProcess error=2, Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden
    at com.vaadin.addon.charts.util.SVGGenerator.startPhantomJS(SVGGenerator.java:129) [vaadin-charts-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at com.vaadin.addon.charts.util.SVGGenerator.getInstance(SVGGenerator.java:142) [vaadin-charts-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
```

How should I do that?

Comment: it appears that the SVG Generator link is broken. Do you know of a current one? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The program expects that the command "plantomjs" is available. Usually, that means that there's a file "phantomjs" under /usr/bin. Are you an admin on the machine? If so, download the right copy of PhantomJS and copy the binary to /usr/bin. You may need to experiment with several versions until you find one that matches your host OS in terms of shared libraries.

If you're not an admin, contact an admin :)

If this is a public web host and you have a shared plan (i. e. not a VPS), ask the hosting company's tech support if you're allowed to run custom binaries at all. You might not be.

Comment: If you are talking about the machine I guess you mean the Wildfly Server and yes I am an admin. Any possibility that I can ship PhantomJS with the application?

Comment: Sure, but you'd have to make sure the Java code can find the phantomjs binary. By default, Linux **doesn't** pick up binaries from the current directory. You'd have to modify PATH, or provide an explicit path, or provide a symlink under /usr/bin.